# Android intent gallery application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I want to view just one image, how can i remove back button on gallery like chrome download intent. 
I want to do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hCFN.jpg)

but now I can move in gallery app like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbB0u.jpg):

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
imageIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)), "image/*");
context.startActivity(imageIntent);
```

Comment: For just a single image... what's the use of an entire Galery?!

Comment: what is `filePath`  value?

Comment: No i have an intent to gallery, i want just to show my downloaded image, but i can move in gallery i think it's wrong, is it posible to create intent to 1 image?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to load an image from your storage directly into an ImageView, if it's what you asked.

Comment: filePath obtained by the method getExternalStorageDirectory() if is available  or getRootDirectory()  /DCIM/myFolder/filename.jpg

Comment: But is it possible to intent just to one image,i think, chrome app using my camera intent to show my downloaded image. I don't want to use it in my app, i just want to show image in gallery app, like chrome